# Generate single xsd file from xml in visual studio

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a xml file. I'm trying to convert it into schema file using the following command
`xsd filename.xml`.

But I get the following error:

> There was an error processing 'filename.xml'.
>     - Nested table 'field name' which inherits its namespace cannot have multiple parent >tables in different namespaces.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but you cannot convert a data XML file to a schema. As your XML file is not a complete representation of all data.
A little example: 
In Europe there is a “new” form of money wiring between banks. It’s called SEPA (You can do research). SEPA is a strict XML schema. 
To simplify:

`<account>111111</account>` is OK for the schema of SEPA, but

`<account>111111 </account>` is NOT OK. (not the space)

As you can see there is no way to extrapolate the schema from one single XML data file. At best you can create a schema manually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But we can create xml schema in visual studio by selecting create schema under XML menu. When i am trying this xsd is spilitted into two files. But i want single xsd file. Any commands to do this.